# Gardner Symbol Timing error detector gain

Tags: symbol-timing

I am trying to design the Symbol timing recovery block for QPSK receiver. 
I have set the loop bandwidth to be 0.005, and damping factor to be 1. I am following **Digital Communications: A Discrete-time Approach by Michael Rice**, for loop filter and Gardner TED design. According to S-curve for gardner TED, the gain Kp comes out to be around 0.1751. I calculated other parameters such as K0 and K1 for the loop filter. However, the loop is not converging, infact its "mu" value is showing a behavior of converging and then diverging.

I think I have calculated the Kp (gain of Gardner TED) wrong. can somebody guide about the value of Kp and gardner TED recovery approach?

Comment: Often this comes down to using time in seconds on the horizontal axis instead of samples in which case you need to include your sample period T (easier to just work in n). For example if you use T accumulators map  to Tz/(z-1) from time integrators, but if you use samples as time they map to z/(z-1). Could that be your issue? Also as a rule of thumb set your loop BW to be 1/20 to 1/50 of the symbol rate- that will allow it to be as fast as possible without tracking out pertinent delay info in your modulation.

Comment: I suggest creating a block diagram of the timing loop model you used, showing the gain (slope) of the error detector as well as your timing offset correction — post that and we may be able to help you further